Über den Zusammenhang von Grammatik und Sprachgebrauch
Am Anfang dieser Frage möchte ich einen Kommentar zitieren, der dieses Problem aufwirft. Ich lasse absichtlich den Autor weg, weil es mir nicht darum geht, jemanden herauszustellen, aber das Zitat bringt etwas zum Ausdruck, das ich so oder so ähnlich schon oft gehört/gelesen habe:

Wenn es um Sprache geht, kommt man mit Logik oft nicht sehr weit. Entscheidend ist der Sprachgebrauch.

Ähnliches sagt etwa Daniel Scholten in seinem Blog. Wenn man das so akzeptiert, dann frage ich mich, was wir hier eigentlich tun. Wenn Sprache (ausschließlich) das ist, was Leute verwenden, ganz egal was es ist, das sie verwenden, dann kann man aufhören, darüber in Kategorien von "richtig" und "falsch" zu sprechen. Dann gibt es "richtig" oder "falsch" überhaupt nicht, sondern nur noch "wird (oft) verwendet" und "wird nicht verwendet". Unter diesem Aspekt ist

Geh ich Kino!

richtiger (weil ziemlich sicher häufiger gebraucht) als die Erkenntnis:

Dieser Satz ist mißgeformt katexochen!

weil das Wort "katexochen" vermutlich sehr selten gebraucht wird (und schon gar nicht von Leuten, die "Kino gegangen" sind).
Mir ist durchaus klar, daß Sprache einer Entwicklung unterliegt und diese Entwicklung immer auch Formen gebiert, die vor Einsetzen derselben anders gelautet haben. Wir schreiben heute nicht mehr "Athem", sondern "Atem". Man kann das "h" als überflüssig (weil stumm) erachten, wiewohl zwischen dem "Thor" und dem "Tor" durchaus ein nicht zu vernachlässigender Unterschied besteht1). Auch das "rau" geht nicht so glatt von der Zunge wie es das "rauh" tat, stimmt aber angeblich. Man kann sich - mit hinreichender Mühe ("Müe"?) auch einbleuen, daß man nun nicht mehr "bleut", sondern "bläut", auch wenn das "bleuen" nicht von "blau" kommt2). Es reicht für das "Stammschreibungsprinzip" ja schon aus, daß es das Wort "blau" überhaupt gibt. (Man könnte das - auch "rau" gibt es ja jetzt - irgendwann beräuen, aber was weiß ich schon?)
Sei dem wie auch immer, Sprache entwickelt sich und das bedeutet, allgemein gesagt, daß sich ihre Regeln ändern. Wenn aber diese Änderungen der Regeln keinerlei Konsistenz unterliegt und diese Änderungen selbst völlig regellos erfolgen können - und genau das insinuiert ja der "Primat der gesprochenen Sprache" - dann stellt sich die Frage, ob nicht jede falsche Wendung schon durch ihren Gebrauch wieder "richtig" wird.
Meine diesbezügliche Frage lautet also:
Um überhaupt soetwas wie "Regeln der Grammatik" aufstellen zu können, bedarf es mindestens einer Abgrenzung zwischen "wird so gebraucht" und "ist falsch/richtig". Für Hinweise bzw. Erläuterungen, worin diese Abgrenzung besteht oder auch, wie sie sinnvoll formuliert werden könnte, wäre ich dankbar.
Mir ist bewußt, daß diese Frage als meinungsbehaftet angesehen werden könnte. Es geht mir aber nicht darum, was der oder jener Antworter für "reine Sprache" erachtet, sondern, was sozusagen die "Mindestanforderung" für eine grammatikalische Regel überhaupt ist. Irgendwo zwischen Beliebigkeit und Regulation, Szylla und Charybdis, muß ja eine solche Trennlinie verlaufen.
------
1) und dies, obwohl sich mancher Thor der Sprachneugestaltung bei näherer Betrachtung durchaus als Tor herausstellt.
2) sondern von althochdeutsch "bliuwan" ("Stange"), von welchem auch das "Pleuel" abstammt.

Eine erste Annäherung: Arten von Grammatiken.

Du wirst hier Grammatik, Vokabular und Orthographie durcheinander.

Die Schreibung einzelner Wörter ist jedenfalls ein ganz schlechtes Beispiel, weil das nichts mit der Grammatik zu tun hat.

@RHa: darum war ja auch das erste Beispiel ein Satz und es ging um Satzststellung, nicht um Schreibung.

Ist die Straßenverkehrsordnung sinnvoll und "zweckmäßig"? Solange ich einen Panzer fahre, nein. Bedenke, dass Sprache ein Mittel sozialer Interaktion ist. Ist man daran nicht interessiert, kann man auf Regeln pfeifen. Ist man daran interessiert, passt man sich der Mehrheit an - und das ergibt idealerweise die Regeln.

Inwiefern hängt der Sinn der Straßenverkehrsordnung davon ab, ob man die Straßen mit einem Panzer befährt? Was denkst Du, woran sich Panzerfahrer halten?

@tofro: Ich halte Dein Argument nicht für stichhaltig, denn diejenigen, die "Geh ich Kino!" sagen, wollen ja auch verstanden werden. Die machen das ja nicht, weil sie Deutsch eine neue Richtung geben wollen, sondern weil sie es nicht anders können. Mein Punkt ist aber: wenn einer von denen hier fragen würde, dann würde man ihm sagen, das sei "falsch". Wenn aber (richtige) Sprache nur der jeweilige Sprachgebrauch ist, dann ist der Satz "richtig", einfach, weil viele ihn verwenden. Irgendwo in diesem Spannungsfeld muß ja wohl die Wahrheit liegen.

@bakunin Innerhalb ihres sozialen Interaktionsraums ist ja "Geh' ich Kino" richtig und verständlich (und wenn ich einen "Duden für Radebrecher" schreiben würde, könnte das ja auch drinstehen). Deren sozialer Interaktionsraum ist allerdings nicht die Mehrheit der Deutschsprecher.

@userunknown Der, den ich beschrieben habe, an gar nichts. Wer nicht verstehen will, versteht auch nicht.

Nun, aus schlechten Prämissen (die Straßenverkehrsordnung ist identisch mit dem, was die Mehrheit tut) folgen unsinnige Beispiele, wie jeder bestätigen wird, der schon einmal einen Panzer im Straßenverkehr gesehen hat. Die meisten Verkehrsteilnehmer sind auch froh, dass sich der Panzerfahrer meist vorhersehbar an die Regeln hält. Und Verkehrsverstöße, die dem eigenen Vorteil gelten, erfordern keinen Panzer. Aber gerade in Anbetracht von Panzern, LKWs, SUVs springen Zweck und Sinn der StVO ins Auge.

Ad "richtig" vs. "falsch"
Ob es "richtig" und "falsch" in der Sprache gibt, ist eine Frage der Betrachtungsweise. Es steht natürlich jedem Menschen frei, eine Verwendungsweise als "falsch" zu klassifizieren. Nun kann sich jeder Mensch sein normatives System basteln, und im Grunde tun wir das auch alle während des Spracherwerbs. Wenn man davon ausgeht, dass es eine "richtige" Sprechweise gibt, ergibt sich die Frage, wie sich aus der Pluralität dessen, wie die Sprache in den jeweiligen Gehirnen ihrer Sprecher:innen repräsentiert ist, eine (einzige) autoritative Grammatik ergibt. Das geschieht nicht anhand irgendwelcher logischer Prinzipien, sondern ist eine historische und soziale Tatsache.
Ad "richtig" weil "logisch"
Unlogische Phänomene in natürlichen Sprachen
Natürliche Sprachen sind voller unlogischer Phänomene. Ein schönes Beispiel ist das englische Wort irregardless. regardless heißt soviel wie "ungeachtet". Die Defintion von irregardless im Wörterbuch lautet schlicht "regardless". irregardless sieht nach allen Regeln der englischen / lateinischen Morphologie wie eine Negation aus, wie in den Gegensatzpaaren wie relevant - irrelevant, proper - improper, patient - impatient, logical - illogical etc. Es ist komplett unlogisch, dass die Negation von regardless dasselbe bedeutet wie regardless. Man kann dieses Phänomen als einen auch andernorts verbreiteten logischen "Fehler" ansehen, die doppelte Negation als einfache Negation zu verstehen. Ungeachtet dessen hat sich die Bedeutung von irregardless per Konvention durchgesetzt. Man kann das bedauern, aber das ändert nichts an dem Gebrauch des Wortes, an der Bedeutung des Wortes. Ein anderer Ansatz sich dem Phänomen zu nähern wäre, zu untersuchen, wie und wann das Denken und Sprechen nicht den Regeln der klassischen Logik folgt.
Diese Art von "unlogischen" Phänomenen wird man in jeder natürlichen Sprache finden. Wer sich in einer Diskussion um sprachliche Richtigkeit auf Logik bezieht, der übersieht, dass auch die eigene Sprache voll solcher "unlogischer" Bestandteile ist. Ein Beispiel im Deutschen: Warum sagen wir Müller, wenn doch Mahler (von mahlen) oder Mühler viel logischer wäre? Müller müsste doch, nach rein morphologischen Regeln, "derjenige, der Müll herstellt", sein.
Kunstsprachen
Beispiele, wie solche prinzipiengeleiteten Grammatiken scheitern, sind die ganzen gescheiterten Kunstsprachen. Einige Leute haben viel Gehirnschmalz investiert, was denn die richtigen Prinzipien für eine gute Sprache seien. Das führt aber nicht dazu, dass diese Sprachen gesprochen werden - das wird von historischen Faktoren bestimmt.
Beispiel: Redundanz vs. Effizienz
Nur als ein Beispiel, wie ein solche "logische", oder "prinzipiengeleitete" Grammatik scheitert: Man könnte beispielsweise Kriterien wie Effizienz und Redundanz als Gütekriterien für ein normatives System heranziehen. Man könnte etwa Effizienz als gut bewerten, und Redundanz als überflüssig und schlecht. Aber keine natürliche Sprache folgt diesen Kriterien. Sprachen entwickeln sich nach dem, was nötig ist. Und es zeigt sich etwa, dass Redundanz einen pragmatischen Wert haben kann, etwa in einem Umfeld, in dem das Signal-Rausch-Verhältnis ungünstig ist. Es kann auch sein, dass Redundanz eine soziale Bedeutung hat. Redundanz in der Sprache könnte etwa im Sinne eines "proof of work" fungieren, und damit soziale Bindung verstärken. (Wenn man sich barocke Bittbriefe durchliest, kann man sich des Eindrucks durchaus nicht erwehren, dass redundante Sprechweise eine soziale Funktion hat.)
Damit kann Redundanz situativ einen positiven Wert haben. Der Wert der Redundanz kann aber auch etwa mit dem Wert der Einfachheit konkurrieren. In deinem Beispiel Geh ich Kino. (im Vergleich zu Ich geh ins Kino) haben sich die Präposition in und der bestimmte Artkel das als redundant und daher obsolet herausgestellt. Dass Kino Neutrum ist, ist auch ohne Artikel klar, und dass sich in nur auf das Kino beziehen kann, ist auch klar - damit enthält Ich geh ins Kino nicht mehr Information als Ich geh in Kino. Dass man nun ins Kino geht und nicht aufs, durchs oder hinters Kino, ist in der Regel aus dem pragmatischen Kontext klar. Damit ist Geh ich Kino nicht unklarer als Ich geh ins Kino. Wer also Geh ich Kino. sagt, misst (implizit) der  Einfachheit einen größeren Stellenwert bei. Und das ist nicht aus logischen Gründen falsch oder richtig, sondern es bewährt sich eben pragmatisch oder nicht.
Die Faktoren, die die Pragmatik beeinflussen, hängen stark von den historischen Umständen ab. Ich kenne mich damit überhaupt nicht aus, aber bei der Entwicklung von Kreolsprachen lassen sich bestimmte Regularitäten feststellen, an denen einige historische Faktoren schön sichtbar werden, die solche Entwicklungen mitbestimmen.
In Diskussionen begegnet man nun mitunter Argumenten der Art, dass eine bestimmte Sprechweise als "richtig" zu gelten habe, weil sie einen bestimmten "logischen" Vorzug habe. Damit ist in der Regel gemeint, dass eine bestimmte Sprechweise einem bestimmten Prinzip "besser" (d.h. mit weniger Ausnahmen bzw. Widersprüchen) entspreche. Damit wird eine Sprechweise, die dem zugrundegelegten Prinzip nicht entspricht, als unlogisch verworfen. Das hat aber nichts mit Logik zu tun, sondern nur mit dem Prinzip. Wer das als logisches Problem charakterisiert, schiebt das Prinzip lediglich unter.
Beispiel: Systematisch vs. Instruktiv
Ein Beispiel ist die Unterscheidung der Sprechweise viertel nach Drei versus viertel Vier (für "15:15 Uhr"). Hier könnte man argumentieren, viertel nach Drei sei deshalb richtiger, weil es instruktiver ist. Dagegen könnte man argumentieren, das System mit viertel Vier (und, analog, dreiviertel Vier für 15:45 Uhr) sei richtiger, weil es systematisch besser passt - weil es nämlich mit dem ebenfalls üblichen Ausdruck halb Vier harmoniert. (Niemand, der viertel nach Drei sagt, sagt ja halb nach Drei für "15:30 Uhr".)
Die beschreibenden Prämissen beider Argumente stimmen, aber sie als normative Argumente zu verwenden, geht völlig am Kern vorbei. Beiden Sprechweisen liegen unterschiedliche Konzeptualisierungen von "eine Stunde" zugrunde (Stunde als Dauer vs. Stunde als Zeitpunkt), die sich beide pragmatisch als sinnvoll erwiesen haben, und es ist im Wesentlichen eine Frage der Gewohnheit (ein positivistischer Aspekt), welche Sprechweise wir wählen (oder akzeptieren). Was hier "richtig" ist, ist was gesprochen wird. Viel mehr kann man da eigentlich nicht sagen.
Reflexion auf die Normativität
Jeder Sprecher hat eine eigene Repräsentation von Sprache im Kopf. Wer entscheidet, welche davon richtig ist, entscheidet also, welcher Sprecher Recht hat. In der Frage nach der "richtigen" Sprech- oder Schreibweise werden also im Grunde Status- und Autoritätskonflikte verhandelt. Wer die exstierenden Sprechweisen kompetenter Sprecher:innen als "falsch" abwertet, der erhebt sich über diese Gruppe. Das kann man natürlich machen, und es hat sicherlich auch wichtige psychologische und soziale Funktionen. Es hat aber mit Wissenschaft nichts zu tun, es dient nicht dem Erwerb von Wissen über die Sprache.
Jedes normative System hat darüber hinaus das Problem, dass es mit Sprachwandel nicht klar kommt. Sprachwandel ist in normativen Systemen per se "falsch". Er ist aber zugleich auch schmerzhaft real. Und jetzt ganz normativ gesprochen: Man macht  sich irgendwann intellektuell lächerlich, wenn man es normativ übertreibt. Wer auf Regeln besteht, die der sprachlichen Realität nicht (mehr) entsprechen, der ist ein König ohne Reich und gibt zu erkennen, dass er die soziale Natur von Sprache nicht versteht. Es zeugt auch von mangelnder Einsicht in die eigene Unbedeutendheit: Die Sprache, die ich heute spreche, war die meiste Zeit der Vergangenheit ganz anders, und wird die meiste Zeit der Zukunft ganz anders sein. Warum soll also gerade diejenige zeitliche, örtliche und soziale Varietät der Sprache, die mir in der Schule eingebläut wurde, die einzig richtige sein?
Relative Normativität
Man kann diesem Problem entgehen, indem man relative Normen einführt. Man könnte etwa sagen, dass eine bestimmte Sprechweise (etwa Er ist älter wie du) im Schwäbischen korrekt ist, aber im Sächsischen nicht. Die Frage ist dann hier, welchen Sprechweisen man den Status von eigenen Varietäten zusprechen will.  Wenn man es ins Extrem treibt, könnte man ja einfach jede Sprechweise einer jeden indivuellen Sprecher:in zu einer "satisfaktionsfähigen " Varietät befördern. Im Grunde muss also auch dieser Ansatz wieder eine implizite soziale Statusfrage beantworten.
Ein deskriptivistisches Verständnis des Begriffs Grammatische Regel
Wenn man ein ausschließlich normatives Verständnis der Grammatik hat, dann wird in den obigen Absätzen nur destruktive Arbeit geleistet. Du hast aber nicht nach der Destruktion des normativen Verständnisses gefragt, sondern nach einem konstruktiven Verständnis, was denn nach der De(kon)struktion noch übrig bleibt. Es gibt eine gute Nachricht:
Man kann Grammatik auch anders denn als ein System von normativen Regeln auffassen. Man kann sie auch als ein System verstehen, das versucht die vorgefundenen Datenpunkte des tatsächlichem Sprachgebrauchs, durch vereinfachende Funktionen abzubilden (genauer gesagt: anzunähern). Der Wert einer solchen Grammatik bemisst sich daran, mit wie wenig Ungenauigkeit (Abweichung der Funktion von den Daten) man für wie viel Vereinfachung bezahlen muss. Unter zwei gleich einfachen Grammatiken würden wir diejenige bevorzugen, die die sprachliche Realität häufiger korrekt nachbildet. Diese Abbildungs-Funktionen sind das, was wir dann als Regeln der Grammatik bezeichnen. Sie sind aber nicht normativ zu verstehen, sondern lassen sich vielleicht eher als Muster auffassen.
Die Aufgabe der Grammatiker:innen ist es, die Grammatik zu verbessern, d.h. möglichst einfache Muster zu erschließen, die möglichst viel der tatsächlich gesprochenen Sprache abbilden. Eine solche Grammatik hat didaktischen Wert, und sie kann auch Gegenstand anderer Wissenschaften sein, etwa der  Soziologie, der Geschichtswissenschaft oder der Kognitionswissenschaften.
Wahrheit und Methode
Viele Menschen, die ein solch normatives Verständnis der Grammatik haben, übertragen das Wahrheitsverständnis der  Naturwissenschaften auf diese Frage. Man hört of Sätze wie "Der Wahrheitsgehalt einer Aussage steigt nicht proportional mit der Anzahl der Leute, die diese Aussage vertreten."
Es gibt aber einen entscheidenden Unterschied zwischen naturwissenschaftlichen Phänomenen und der Sprache: Anders als die physikalischen sind die linguistischen Phänomene soziale Konstrukte. Der "Wahrmacher" für sprachliche Richtigkeit liegt nur innerhalb der Menschen, die die Sprache sprechen. Das ist bei physikalischen oder chemischen Gesetzen anders.
Sicherlich ist die schönste (oder meinetwegen die "richtigste") Sprache der Welt eine Sprache, die von niemandem gesprochen wird (so wie Mascha Kalékos Gedicht, das sie nie schrieb, und wie Wittgensteins "Schmerz, den niemand fühlt"). Was aber ist der Wert einer normativen Grammatik, die man nur selbst erfüllt? Es ist eine Einsamkeitsmaschine.

"Müller" kommt sehr wohl von "mahlen", weil das einmal ein starkes Verbb war und das Präteritum "mul" lautete.

@bakunin Klar kommt es von "mahlen", und natürlich hat es historische Gründe. Das ist ja genau mein Punkt - es gibt historische Faktoren, die über eine einfache prinzipienbasierte Logik hinausgehen und die Sprache bestimmen. Als sich die Deklination von mahlen geändert hat, hat sich der Müller nicht mitgeändert - und damit entstand eine Inkonsistenz. Wer beschwert sich darüber? Niemand, wir sind es gewohnt, Konvention schlägt Konsistenz.

"Historische Gründe" ist ja auch eine Art von Logik: es ist so, weil es sich aus ... entwickelt hat. Auch Ableitungen und Komposita haben zwar bestimmte aber nicht immer gleiche Systeme: ein "Putenschnitzel" ist eines aus Putenfleisch, ein "Kinderschnitzel" aber was anderes. Ein "XX-er" kann jemand sein, der XX produziert (Mauer-Maurer) oder jemand, der mit "XX hantiert/zu tun hat" (Medizin-Mediziner, schneiden-Schneider), andererseits aber nicht "jemand, der XX zu Hause stehen hat" oder "jemand, der XX ißt". Es folgt also auch die Konvention einer gewissen Logik.

„Entscheidend ist der Sprachgebrauch.“?

Das ist die pragmatische Sichtweise auf die reale Situation.
Das ist auch die Kapitulation vor der Realität.
Das ist ebenfalls die wortgewordene Flucht in die Gleichgültigkeit.
Das ist nach Jellinek die linguistische Variante seiner normativen Kraft des Faktischen.

Oder: machen „es“ viele, wird es normal.
Richtig muss „es“ deswegen nicht sein.
„Geh ich Kino“ ist als hilfloser Ausdruck eines Lernenden hinnehmbar, sofern damit umgehend eine Korrektur verbunden ist. Ein Glück, wer Dank erntet.
Dergleichen Gestammel ist in Chats nicht unüblich, unabhängig von den deutschen Sprachkenntnissen. Wer Teenager in seiner Familie hat, wird wissen, wovon ich spreche und woran ich leide. Eine Korrektur der sprachlichen Gepflogenheiten wird dort als Eingriff in die Souveränität betrachtet – außerdem sei das Chat-Sprache. Dank? Nein, nur Verbalinjurien!
Es bleibt die Hoffnung auf baldige linguistische Genesung, unterstützt von den nimmermüden Korrekturen der liebenden Altvorderen.
Aber wie geht man mit denen um, die man nicht unbedingt liebt?
Als da wären zahlreiche Menschen, die ihren Bildungsstand durch möglichst viele Anglizismen dokumentieren möchten. Download ist Sprachgebrauch wie downloaden. Siehe 2. Muss das sein? Zugegeben: Runterholen taugt wenig als deutsche Übersetzung. Laden statt Download geht nicht? Hochladen statt Upload? Und laden statt downloaden? Sicher gibt es Begriffe, für die kein deutsches Wort existiert. Wie z. B. Streaming. Ist akzeptiert. Musicstreaming oder Music-Streaming ist zu viel. Wenn schon, dann Musik-Streaming oder etwas umständlicher Streaming von Musik. Das trennt den fremdsprachlichen Begriff und verhindert eine unschöne Substantivkomposition.
Use Cases ist nicht nur zu viel, sondern peinlich. Dergleichen ist nicht nur bei der Spezies der Seltsamen üblich, die als Marketingspezialisten ihre Brötchen verdienen und deswegen vor allem Worthülsen glauben produzieren zu müssen. Auch Heise und selbst das Leibnitz-Institut verwenden diesen Begriff.
Der sprachliche Missbrauch gipfelt aber nicht in fremdsprachlichen Ausdrücken, sondern in einer beliebigen Verwendung von Begriffen. Was heute als R&B bezeichnet wird, hat mit dem ursprünglichen Rhythm & Blues so viel zu tun wie eine Oper mit einem Opa. Und frei nach Wilhelm Busch erlaube ich mir zu ergänzen: R&B als störend wird empfunden, wenn er mit Geräusch verbunden.
Die größere Bedrohung der sprachlichen Präzision liegt in dem unüberlegten Gebrauch von alltäglichen Begriffen. Ein Beispiel? Was bedeuten Billigung, Toleranz und Akzeptanz? Sind die Begriffe synonym? Oder wo liegen die Unterschiede? Ist Missbilligung das Antonym zu Billigung?
Die Beantwortung dieser Fragen entpuppt sich als zeitintensiv. Das Schema:

Einen Begriff erfassen, definieren und durch Textbeispiele belegen.
Synonyme suchen, die in den Textbeispielen austauschbar sind.
Gleichlautende Begriffe unterschiedlicher Bedeutung als eigenen Begriff erfassen.
Verwandte Wortarten zuordnen, also Nomen, Adjektive und Verben in Familien organisieren.

Was tun?

Nicht kapitulieren.
Den sprachlichen Missbrauch korrigieren.
Den Mut haben, sich unbeliebt zu machen.
Es besser machen.


Wer bestimmt denn, was richtig und falsch ist?

Warum ist es eine "Kapitulation" vor der Realität statt eine "Einsicht" in die Realität? In der Färbung deiner Worte scheint mir viel Enttäuschung und fast schon Verzweiflung mitzuschwingen, aber man kann diese Färbungen auch einfach positiv umkehren. Warum ist die Anpassung der eigenen Vorstellung an die Realität etwas Negatives? Oft begreifen wir das doch als etwas positives, als Erkenntnisgewinn.

dwds.de ist eine Referenz, was richtig ist.

Use Cases statt Anwendungsfälle, Location statt Ort, etwas cancellen statt aufheben/streichen ist ein unreflektierter Sprachgebrauch. Dergleichen braucht die Menschheit so dringend wie eine bellende Wanduhr. Und so alleine bin ich mit meiner Meinung nicht.

Erstens: irgendwoher muß das, was in dwds.de steht, ja auch herkommen. Das einfach als "Referenz" zu bezeichnen, greift also zu kurz.

Zweitens: den grundsätzlichen Unterschied zwischen Anglizismen, Latinismen, Graecismen und allen anderen Fremdwörtern sehe ich nicht. Wer unreflektiert was gegen "Anglizismen" hat, sollte also "Englischwörter" sagen und wer eine "unschöne Substantivkomposition" vermeiden will, der sollte sich mit "die Reihung von Hauptwörtern hintereinander ohne Abstand" bescheiden. Wobei das germanische Fremdwort "stehen" in "Abstand" auch diskutabel wäre.

Drittens: Worte und Bezeichnungen unterliegen ständig Bedeutungsänderungen. Wenn der Lehrer die Schüler auffordert, "die Hefte" herauszuholen, rechnet er auch nicht damit, daß Schwertgriffe auf den Tisch geknallt werden - Auch wenn das im 14. Jahrhundert vielleicht noch anders gewesen wäre. Daß "R&B" heute was anderen bedeutet als "Rhythm @ Blues" ist nichts anderes - mal abgesehen davon, daß ein Miles Davies oder Chick Corea unter "Jazz" auch was anderes verstanden haben als Louis Armstrong oder Bix Beiderbecke. Was also war der "richtige Jazz"?

Zur Kompetenz siehe https://www.dwds.de/d/ueber-uns. Wenn du eine bessere Quelle kennst, lass es mich wissen.

Anglizismus ist als deutsches Wort existent. Weiter bin ich nicht unreflektiert gegen Angliszismen, sondern ich bin gegen den unreflektirten Gebrauch von Anglizismen. Das klingt ähnlich, ist es aber nicht. Ich vermeide Anglizismen und andere Fremdwörter, wenn es ein passendes deutsches Wort gibt.

Bedeutungsänderungen gibt es, die sind eher fließend. Bei dem Sprachgebrauch orientiere ich mich an der Gegenwart, das 14. Jahrhundert war vor meiner Zeit. Jazz kannte auch zu Chick Corea Zeiten verschiedene Stilrichtungen. Verschiedene Stilrichtungen in einem Begriff zu bündeln, halte ich für vertretbar. Völlig unterschiedliche Musikstile gleich zu benennen, halte ich für keinen Gewinn.
Meine Beiträge habe ich als Antwort auf deine Frage verstanden, was wir hier eigentlich tun.
